# Rules of inference for exclusive disjunction and logical biconditional

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

[Here are the rules of inference in natural calculus of propositions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yujhB.png) I'd like to extend this calculus (conservatively) adding exclusive disjunction $\oplus$ and logical biconditional $\sim$ and obtain a complete system. There are many ways to describe their 'behavior', for instance, 2 rules:

$$\cfrac{\Gamma,\neg A\vdash B;\quad \Gamma,\neg B\vdash A}{\Gamma\vdash A\oplus B};\qquad\cfrac{\Gamma\vdash A\oplus B}{\Gamma,A,B\vdash}$$

would be enough for strict disjunction.

My question is: which way is traditional (if there is such a tradition) and most convinient?

Comment: In principle, the rules of your system must use **only one** connective; thus, you have to avoid $\lnot$ in the above rules.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, hm, thank you, I've never thought about it. So, shall I replace the first rule with $\cfrac{\Gamma,A,B\vdash}{\Gamma\vdash A\oplus B}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For bi-conditional, I would suggest:

$\dfrac {\Gamma, A \vdash B \ \ \ \ \Gamma, B \vdash A}{\Gamma \vdash A \leftrightarrow B} \text { for }(\leftrightarrow \text I)$

and the pair:

$\dfrac {\Gamma \vdash A \leftrightarrow B}{\Gamma, A \vdash B} \ \ \ \dfrac {\Gamma \vdash A \leftrightarrow B}{\Gamma, B \vdash A} \text { for }(\leftrightarrow \text E)$

---

For exclusive or, the pair:

$\dfrac {\Gamma, A \vdash  \ \ \ \ \Gamma \vdash B}{\Gamma \vdash A \oplus B} \ \ \ \dfrac {\Gamma, \vdash A  \ \ \ \ \Gamma, B \vdash}{\Gamma \vdash A \oplus B} \text { for }(\oplus \text I)$

and the corresponding for $(\oplus \text E)$, based on the fact that an $\oplus$ True formula can produce cases: either $A$ False and $B$ True or the symmetric one:

$\dfrac {\Gamma, A \vdash  \ \ \ \ \Gamma \vdash A \oplus B}{ \Gamma \vdash B} \ \ \ \dfrac {\Gamma, \vdash A  \ \ \ \ \Gamma \vdash A \oplus B}{\Gamma, B \vdash}$

Comment: Yes, that's the most natural way, in my opinion. The main part of my question accords to exclusive disjunction. What would you suggest?

Comment: Oh, great, could you please clarify what do you mean by "corresponding for ($\oplus$E)"?

Comment: @Alexander E => Elimination. The person listed the introduction and elimination rules for both connectives.

Comment: @Math3147, I guessed what "E" means. But which $\oplus$-elimination rule was offered?

Comment: @Alexander They didn't offer one from the looks of it and just assumed they could be replicated from my guess similarly to the one up top.